# Powershell - keep specific word in a string

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I'm doing AD extract and I sort the field "distinguishedname" and I want to keep only a specific part of the value that represent the "parent OU" of the user itself.

I'm running this command to do an add extract of all users:

```
import-module activedirectory
get-aduser -filter * -properties *| Select-Object -Property SamAccountName,CN,co,ExtensionAttribute10,extensionAttribute11,extensionAttribute12,EmailAddress,whenCreated,Enabled,LastLogonDate,accountexpirationdate,distinguishedname  |Sort-Object -Property Name | Export-Csv -Delimiter ";" -path "u:\theOutFile_NOFILTER_July.txt"
```

The column `"distinguishedname"` look like this:

```
distinguishedname
CN=familly\, user,OU=Remote Users,OU=New York,OU=My,DC=Company,DC=Local
CN=nameless\, cat,OU=Remote Users,OU=Ottawa,OU=My,DC=Company,DC=Local
CN=Cameron\, James,OU=Regular Users,OU=Hollywood,OU=My,DC=Company,DC=Local
CN=Bon\, Jean,OU=regular Users,OU=Springfield,OU=My,DC=Company,DC=Local
```

**Note July 10**
some time I will hit those line:

```
CN=Dog\, Cesar,OU=Special Accounts,OU=Regular Users,OU=Alma,OU=My,DC=Company,DC=Local
CN=keys\, Alicia,OU=Special Accounts,OU=Regular Users,OU=Paris,OU=My,DC=Company,DC=Local
CN=Clansy\, Door,OU=Map Drives,OU=Remote Users,OU=Rome,OU=My,DC=Company,DC=Local
```

In those case I am getting result such `Remote Users` an `Regular Users` instead of the City. I've tried some modification in your command you gave but in vain.

But I would like the first command to return this result instead:

```
distinguishedname
New York
Ottawa
Hollywood
Springfield
```

I can't effort to find how.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select-Object has a very versatile feature to create calculated properties using a hash in the place of a property name, where the key "Name" is set to the name of the calculated property (effectively, the column heading), and "Expression" is set to a code block that determines the value of the property, for each object in the pipeline. This will do what you want:

```
Get-Aduser -Filter * -Properties * | Select-Object -Property SamAccountName,CN,co,ExtensionAttribute10,extensionAttribute11,extensionAttribute12,EmailAddress,whenCreated,Enabled,LastLogonDate,accountexpirationdate,@{Name='distinguishedname'; Expression={[regex]::match($_.distinguishedname,'OU=.+?OU=(.+?),(OU|DC)=').Groups[1].Value}} | Sort-Object -Property Name | Export-Csv -Delimiter ";" -Path "u:\theOutFile_NOFILTER_July.txt"
```

Here's a breakdown what's going on:

- `Name='distinguishedname'` tells it to create a new column called 'distinguishedname'. I used that name to match your example of the output you're looking for, but it doesn't have to be the name of an existing property. It would probably make more sense to change the name to something more descriptive of the values you're calculating, e.g. `Name="parentOU"`.
- `[regex]::match` is used to extract the desired portion from **$_.distinguishedname** using the regular expression `OU=.+?OU=(.+?),(OU|DC)=`, which isolates the name of the second OU in the list using a match group.
- `.Groups[1].Value` returns the value of the first match group (the part matched by the contents of the first set of parentheses). **.Value** on its own without **.Groups[1]** would return the entire matched string, from the first **OU=** to the **=** following name of the parent OU. The following would work just as well, using zero-width assertions instead of a match group: `[regex]::match($_.distinguishedname,'(?<=OU=.+?OU=).+?(?=,(OU|DC)=)').Value`

Comment: i've update my initial post, i've ran though some exeption that might need your help to be solve. Your explanation is great but I don't see where i need to make the change to extract the sting between OU= and "OU=MY" to get the City field

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're asking. The change you need to make is to replace the single word **distinguishedname** with `@{Name='distinguishedname'; Expression={[regex]::match($_.distinguishedname,'OU=.+?OU=(.+?),(OU|DC)=').Groups[1].Value}}` in the Get-ADUser command. Just replace your Get-ADUser command with the revised version in my answer. (I also recommend changing `Name='distinguishedname'` to `Name='parentOU'` or `Name='City'`, since that column no longer contains distinguished names).

Comment: BTW, if you're asking what it is that extracts the city (parent OU) name from the distinguished name, it's the regex. Either `[regex]::match($_.distinguishedname,'OU=.+?OU=(.+?),(OU|DC)=').Groups[1].Value` or `[regex]::match($_.distinguishedname,'(?<=OU=.+?OU=).+?(?=,(OU|DC)=)').Value` will evaluate to the name of the second OU in the value of the distinguishedname property of each object passed by Get-ADUser.

Comment: Big thanks, I think what I tried to explain was not clear, I will try to get what I want y doing many query and append the restult of the different query to the log file. Thanks for you priceless help